# fetch json value with no key using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, key

i am having trouble fetch JSON using jQuery, if possible someone tell me what mistake i made because my code is not working

**data.json file contain**

```js
{
"value1",
"value2",
"value3",
"value4"
}
```

**and here is my jquery code**

```js
$.getJSON( "data.json", function( data ) {
  $.each( data, function( val ) {
    alert(val);
  });
});
```

Comment: you use the wrong brackets in the json file. use `[]` instead of `{}`

Comment: If it is possible then use array because you genrated wrong json.
This link will help you http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp

Comment: thank you guys, i tried Akash Rajbanshi example and it worked for me ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `[]` instead of `{}` in the json file as suggested in the comment as your current json is not a valid JSON. Then you can access the file data this way.

```
$.each(data, function(i,val) {
    alert(val);
  });
```

Notice, that your current code only access the index of the value but not the actual value. Place the both parameter `i` and `val` to get both index and value from the file.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wy8tb5pe/1/)

Comment: that helped me a lot now my file size is reduced, thank you so much